# Replacing info in Access

Tags: sql, forms, ms-access, vba

I have a table within Access that looks similar to this:

```
ProductID - ClientID - ProductName - Description
118       -  5       - Full Search - xxxx
35        -  2       - Update      - xxxx
105       -  7       - O & E       - xxxx
```

I want to be able to call the ProductID and have it return the ProductName field.

```
ProductID = Forms!Orders.Product.Value()
```

Any help?

Comment: I figured i could do this with an RecordSet() - however, my noob skills don't give me much knowledge to go on.

Comment: Are you asking for a VBA solution or a VB.Net one?. It seems that you require VBA but you have tagged your question with vb.net.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [DLookUp](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/208786):

```
 DlookUp("ProductName","Products","ProductID=" & SomeNumericID)
```

There are other ways, but you need to say where you are coming from and going to.

Comment: Thank you. I just figured it out this way as soon as you posted this.